# graphql filter based on internal fragments (gatsbyJS)

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Why is this not possible? In the sense that it looks like I have no access to any property accessed through an internal fragment such as `... on File`

[codebox](https://711808k40x.sse.codesandbox.io/___graphql?query=%7B%0A%20%20books%3A%20allMarkdownRemark(filter%3A%20%7Bparent%3A%20%7BsourceInstanceName%3A%20%7Beq%3A%20%22%22%7D%7D%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20File%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sourceInstanceName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) from [gatsby-docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/running-queries-with-graphiql/)

```
{
  books: allMarkdownRemark(filter: {parent: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "whatever"}}}) {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        parent {
          ... on File {
            sourceInstanceName
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error: Field is not defined by type NodeFilterInput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's a resolver authors responsibility.

**You can compare it to general function arguments and returned result. In graphQL both are strictly defined/typed.**

In this case, for query `allMarkdownRemark` you have

```
allMarkdownRemark(
  filter: MarkdownRemarkFilterInput
  limit: Int
  skip: Int
  sort: MarkdownRemarkSortInput
): MarkdownRemarkConnection!
```

... so possible arguments are only `filter`, `limit`, `skip` and `sort`. Argument  `filter` has defined shape, too - it has to be `MarkdownRemarkFilterInput` type. You can only use properties defined in this type for `filter` argument.

**This is by design, this is how designer created resolver and his intentions about how and what arguments are handled.**

It's like pagination - you don't have to use any of result fields as arguments as `skip` and `limit` are for record level. This way those arguments are not related to fields at all. They are used for some logic in resolver. `filter` argument is used for logic, too ... but **it's deleveloper decision to choose and cover filtering use cases**.

It's impossible to cover all imaginable filters on all processed data layers and properties, ... for `parent` you can only use `children`, `id`, `internal` and `parent` properties and subproperties (you can explore them in playground).

Of course it's not enough to extend type definition to make it working with another argument - **it's about code to handle it**.

If you need onother filtering logic, you can write your own resolver (or modify forked gatsby project) for your file types or other source.

Comment: Totally right, and I see GatsbyJS has docs about how to create resolvers https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/